# Highcharts fix plotlines threshold show very near at bottom of the container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using react with chart type is stockChart, 2 series line and area.
The threshold line (yellow line) show very near at bottom of the container.
How can I config in any case threshold line will not show very near at top and bottom of chart container ?

Tks for your help.
[img](https://prnt.sc/5MJsRLej74IW)

```
plotOptions: {
column: {
    maxPointWidth: 2
},
series: {
    fillOpacity: 0.1,
        marker: {
        enabled: false,
            states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    shadow: false,
        dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
    },
    stacking: 'normal',
        negativeColor: '#ea3943',
            lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
        hover: {
            lineWidth: 1
        },
        inactive: {
            opacity: 1
        }
    },
    pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0.1
},
area: {
    fillOpacity: 0.6
}
```

}

Comment: It seems the threshold is on the yAxis.min level. Try out to change the yAxis min to lower.